# Is there a way to customize the characters used in fold column?

Tags: folding, options

Seems to me that `fillchars` option doesn't include these characters.

Comment: `fillchars` only allows customization of the horizontal lines that delimit folds. AFAIK you can't change the fold column `+`, `-`, `|` markers. (You can change the highlighting, e.g. fg/bg colors...that's only customization I'm aware of.)

Comment: correct, there is no way to change it

Comment: `fillchars` now has `foldopen`, foldclose` and `foldsep` for this purpose - https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31509/29308