# change fold sign character

Tags: highlight, folding, signs

I know per my question [remove trailing dashes in foldtext](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21862/remove-trailing-dashes-in-foldtext) that I can remove the trailing dashes from collapsed fold lines. When a fold is 'open', the sign column has pipe characters '|'. I looked at the help page and tried searching for fold, but no luck. Is there any way to change the pipe characters to something else?

edit: `help foldcolumn` says `&fdc` is the width of the column. `help folding` with a search for 'pipe' and 'character' unfortunately brings up nothing.

Comment: I believe it is in fact the foldcolumn—check that help page to see if it has what you are looking for. Also, do you need accounts merged? The usernames are similar but different (capitalization, etc.) and you claim to be OP of linked Q...

Comment: Repeating my question: it looks like there are several accounts with this user name or a variation of it. Are they all you? Why separate accounts? Do you want them merged? You accrue reputation better with a single account...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yep, same OP. posted questions as guest. I Don't care about reputation, and I don't use SO often enough to warrant making an account, saving the password somewhere, linking it to my email etc.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, in answer to your question, `help foldcolumn` says `&fdc` is the width of the column. `help folding` with a search for 'pipe' and 'character' unfortunately brings up nothing.

Comment: No, the characters used in the foldcolumn are hard coded.

Comment: @Myc3lium well, i guess thats up to you... but i find it unfortunate. Also confusing :P

Comment: I meant that foldcolumn =/= signcolumn

Answer (score 3):

Its possible now using `'fillchars'` (from the help):

```
      item          default     Used for
      ...
      foldopen:c    '-'         mark the beginning of a fold
      foldclose:c   '+'         show a closed fold
      foldsep:c     '|'         open fold middle character
```

For example, `set fillchars+=foldopen:▾,foldsep:│,foldclose:▸`

*Compatibility*: Vim 8.2.2524+ or Neovim 0.5.0+

Comment: It would be worth citing the exact version of vim this is available in (I *know* it's not available in 8.2.2300)

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3aca5a6fbcfbf5f4492b9ea0c4308ac524d33606#diff-442131dbc53d601ff38edcc95c73c09272934f92f7cf6601738cc6ceaf8a1e48

Comment: Vim 8.2.2524+ or Neovim 0.5.0+

Answer (score 1):

(Moved to a separate answer for visibility)

According to @Christian Brabandt the characters used for this purpose are hardcoded.